# Create an unsorted heap (left to right) using given array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, heap, binary-tree

I've been trying to solve this problem for two days and I can't figure out how to represent an array to a heap(left to right). I tried looking for answer on other websites but I can't find one.

The problem is there is a given array. For example ...

```
{26,5,3,2,1,1...}
```

I need to convert it to an unordered heap like this.

```
    26
   /  \
  5    3
 / \   
2   1
```

What I have done so far is this, but I can't figure out how to check if left most node childrens is filled first before going to the right nodes.

```
package myTest;

public class UnsortedBT {

static int[] unsortedArr = new int[]{26,5,3,2,1,1,10,2,4};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    UnsortedBT c = new UnsortedBT();
    BinaryTree tree = c.new BinaryTree(unsortedArr[0]);
    for(int i=1 ;i<unsortedArr.length;i++)
    {   
        BinaryTree newTree = c.new BinaryTree(unsortedArr[i]);
        tree.insert(newTree);
    }

    System.out.println(tree.left.left.right.data);
}

public class BinaryTree{
    private BinaryTree right;
    private BinaryTree left;
    private int data;        

    public BinaryTree(int s){
        data = s;
        right = null;
        left = null;           
    }

    public int checkTree(){
        if(left == null && right == null){
            return 1;
        }else if(left == null){
            return 1 + right.checkTree();
        }else if(right == null){
            return 1 + left.checkTree();
        }else{
            return 1 + left.checkTree() + right.checkTree();
        }
    }

    public void insert(BinaryTree bt){
        if(left == null){
            setLeft(bt);
        }else if(right == null){
            setRight(bt);
        }else{
            int leftCheck = left.checkTree();
            int rightCheck = right.checkTree();

            // The problem is lies here
            if(leftCheck==rightCheck||left!=null&&left==null){
                  left.insert(bt);
            }else{
                right.insert(bt);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setLeft (BinaryTree l){ left  = l; }
    public void setRight(BinaryTree r){ right = r; }        
}
}
```

Comment: This blog entry and the one that follows should help you out: http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/29/a-better-way-to-do-it-the-heap/

Comment: That is for sorted heap sir. I'm doing unsorted.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unordered heap." A heap has a particular structure and it is in fact ordered. It looks like you're trying to create a balanced, left-filled binary tree from an arbitrary array. It just so happens that the array representation you've selected creates a tree that is a max-heap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I think U are doing DFS which is causing a confusion
U Could do same problem in BFS manner

```
  queue.add(new Node(a[0])//  Initilize queue with first element
    intilize array index counter variable i=0


    while(queue.isnotempty)
        {
        node currentnode=queue.deque();
        int left=2*i+1
        int right=2*i+2
        currentnode.left=new Node(left>array.lenght-1?null:array[left]); //put left variable
   currentnode.right=new Node(right>array.lenght-1?null:array[left]); //put   right node
    if(currennode.left!=null)
    queue.enquer(currennode.left);

    if(currennode.right!=null)
    queue.enquer(currennode.right);
     i++;
    }
```

Algorithm works on bfs We are doing BFS traversal 
incrementing index one by one and adding childrens to child node to queue and then dequeing it

Find The updated working code

```
package com;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;

class Node {

    int node;
    Node left = null;
    Node right = null;

    public Node(int value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.node = node;
    }

}
public class ArrayToHeap {



public static void main(String... args)
{


    int [] array = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6};


    Node head=new Node(1);
    Queue<Node> queue = new LinkedList();
    queue.add(head);

int i=0;
    while (!queue.isEmpty())
    {
        Node currentnode=queue.remove();

        int left=2*i+1;
        int right=2*i+2;

        currentnode.left=left>array.length-1?null:new Node(array[left]);
        currentnode.right=right>array.length-1?null:new Node(array[right]);

        if(currentnode.left!=null)
            queue.add(currentnode.left);

        if(currentnode.right!=null)
            queue.add(currentnode.right);
        i++;
    }



}
}
```

Comment: I will try this once I get home , thank you!. Why did you use queue.add then suddenly queue.enquer ? What is the reason behind this?

Comment: I think there's a bug here. When assigning the nodes, you're always creating a new node. Your ternary operator is in the wrong place. You should have `currentnode.left=left>array.length-1?null:new Node(array[left])`.

Comment: Hi folks it is a Pseodocode just for rough idea how to solve there may be little bug or boundary value  constrains  that needed to be handled .I just put it to give a idea how to solve

Answer (score 0):

If your node is i then you can assign child as 2i + 1 and 2i + 2.

```
loop(i to n/2){
   iParent(i)     = i;
   iLeftChild(i)  = 2*i + 1;
   iRightChild(i) = 2*i + 2;
}
```

Try something like this.

Comment: Sorry , but I dont understand your solution. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to build a binary tree from the array. The example you give shows that the tree is represented in the array in breadth-first order. That is, the item at index 0 in the array is the root. The next two items are the children of the root. The next four are those children's children, etc.

As Aman Sachan pointed out in his answer, you can determine a node's children by the following:

```
left child index = (node index)*2 + 1
right child index = (node index)*2 + 2
```

Using that information, you can build the tree recursively, depth-first, in the same way that you do an inorder traversal of a binary tree. Something like this pseudocode.

```
tree_node build_tree(array, index)
{
    // if the index is beyond the end of the array, then there's
    // no node here.
    if (index >= array.length)
        return null;

    // create the new node with the proper value.
    new_node = new tree_node(array[index]);

    // build the left node
    new_node.left = build_tree(array, (2*index) + 1);

    // and the right node
    new_node.right = build_tree(array, (2*index) + 2);

    // and then return the newly-built node
    return new_node;
}
```

You call it by passing the array and the first index:

```
tree_node root_node = build_tree(array, 0);
```

There's another solution that mirrors the breadth-first traversal of a binary tree. If you understand breadth-first traversal, you should be able to derive the solution on your own.